# Intent definition in Manifest file

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I would like to start my own SMS editor when user selects "Send message" from contacts application. How do I define intent in manifest file to allow passing contact details to the editor?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many "contacts applications" for Android, not just one. You declined to indicate which "contacts application" you are referring to.

Some "contacts applications" may use `ACTION_SENDTO` with an `smsto:` `Uri` for sending an SMS. In that case, you can add an `<intent-filter>` to your manifest watching for an `android.intent.action.SENDTO` `<action>` and a `<data>` with `scheme` of `smsto:`. That should trigger your activity to be an option for the user.

However, bear in mind that not all "contacts applications" may use this.

Comment: I am referring to a native contacts application. Please let me know if I should add any extra details. Can you please post an example of such an <intent-filter>? Thanks