# How can I add an option when making an outgoing call?

Tags: android, telephony

I am trying to create an app that functions like skype. When you have skype installed and try to make a call, after pressing the CALL_BUTTON, it will ask the user to choose which service to use ("Complete action using" >> Dialer or Skype).

I am hoping to add another option that would call my activity. I have been using intent-filters on xml but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    <activity android:name=".OutgoingCallActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Anyone can provide me some snippet of their code? Thanks you so much.

Comment: my question is "how can I add my app as one of the options on making an outgoing call?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to catch the broadcasted message:

`<receiver android:name=".your.receiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="-1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

In there you can decide weather you want to open a window or not and choose to block the broadcast proceeding to other receivers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this doesn't seem to give me the result I am looking for.

Comment: You can also try to catch the call as a default action with:                               '<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />'

Comment: Yea it works pretty much the same way, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798179/intent-definition-in-manifest-file)